# como ordenar los container

Tags: php, css

este es el codigo necesito que los card que me cargue (segun lo mandado por la base de datos) se pongan una al lado de la otra. 3 por fila mas o menos

```
<?php
  foreach ($listaServicios as $item) {                   
    $servicio_id = $item['servicio_id'];
    $nombre = $item['nombre'];
    $descripcion = $item['descripcion'];
    $foto = $item['foto'];
    $precio = $item['precio'];
 
    // $arrLength = sizeof($listaProductos);
    echo "
      <div class='container'>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <a href="servicio/ver?id=$servicio_id">
              <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
                <img src="$foto" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">$nombre</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">$precio</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   "; } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta metiendo en el foreach todos los divs y debe meter dentro del ciclo solo las iteraciones para las cards. Además debería mejorar el uso de PHP y HTML juntos.

Sus cards están teniendo una ancho de 9 columnas cada una de las 12 que Bootstrap maneja, si solo quiere 3 por fila debe ponerle 4 columnas por cada una

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class="row">
<?php
  foreach ($listaServicios as $item) {                   
    $servicio_id = $item['servicio_id'];
    $nombre = $item['nombre'];
    $descripcion = $item['descripcion'];
    $foto = $item['foto'];
    $precio = $item['precio'];
 
    // $arrLength = sizeof($listaProductos);
?>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <a href="servicio/ver?id=<?php echo $servicio_id ?>">
    <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
      <img src="<?php echo $foto ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $nombre ?></h5>
        <p class="card-text"><?php echo $precio ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

```
} 
?>
```

Despues debe cerrar el ciclo foreach con **}**, lo pongo así porque no pude meterlo en el mismo bloque.